# talend - split one row into multiple rows based on some logic

Tags: oracle, talend

Currently here is my flow:

```
tOracleInput -> tMap -> tFileOutput
```

The output of the select statement in tOracleInput is something like this:

```
ID    |  Name   |  Amount  |  PercentageOfMixed  | IsMixedFlag
1      C0000001    100.00       0.55                   Y
```

Now the logic is:
- if isMixedFlag is 'Y', the number of output should be 2, each with the percentage of the Amount
- the value for Name field of each row is appended with prefix A or B.

Output:

```
ID    |  Name   |  Amount  | IsMixedFlag
1      C0000001A    55.00        Y
2      C0000001B    45.00        Y
```

Is this feasible?

Thanks in advance for all the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT ID, Name, Amount * PercentageOfMixed Amount, IsMixedFlag
FROM your_table
WHERE IsMixedFlag = Y
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Amount * (1 - PercentageOfMixed) Amount, IsMixedFlag
FROM your_table
WHERE IsMixedFlag = Y
ORDER BY ID
```

This might not be the exact result what you are trying to achive but this can give you the idea to achieve your end result.

Comment: i say i would not like to go with union all, because actually our query is big and has a lot of joins, so putting it on union all would execute it twice.  that's why i'm thinking if this can be done via talend instead